# Raven DB LINQ Where->Any Query not working

Tags: linq, ravendb

I'm getting a weird (non-)result from Raven DB.

I'm running the latest stable build, v2.5.2666, on both the client and the server.

What I want to retrieve is "the first DeployProject document who contains a Component object whose Id value is 'x'".

So the first thing I tried is:

```
var project = _documentSession.Query<DeployProject>()
      .FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ComponentList.Any(j=>j.Id == componentId));
```

But that returned null, even though I know the data is correct.  To verify I'm not crazy, I added a .ToList() to middle, so it will pull out all of the documents into memory query it there.

```
var project = _documentSession.Query<DeployProject>()
      .ToList()
      .FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ComponentList.Any(j=>j.Id == componentId));
```

And that DID work, so my logic and data is correct.  But of course it's really inefficient, the whole idea is that I only want to pull the single document that contains the relevant child record.

So there definitely seems to be an issue with how Raven is querying the index, since the data is definitely there, and I can retrieve it if I pull everything into memory and run the same LINQ query.

My hope (fear?) was that the index was stale, so I told it to give me fresh data:

```
var project = _documentSession.Query<DeployProject>()
      .Customize(i=>i.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
      .FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ComponentList.Any(j=>j.Id == componentId));
```

But again I got null.  It seems that Raven is just not treating the LINQ statement the way that I would expect, i.e. the way that LINQ to objects would work.  I know that there canbe some differences, but this should be a pretty straightforward query that I would expect to work.

Anyone have any ideas?  Am I missing something simple?

EDIT: According to Raven's documentation, it seems like this should work without any adventurous indexing:

http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/using-linq-to-query-ravendb

> Other than the Where clause, there are several other useful operators
>   you could use to filter results.
>
> Any can be used on collections of objects (or primitive lists) in your
>   entities to return only those who satisfies a condition. RavenDB also
>   supports an In operator, to make reverse Any comparisons easier:

```
// Return only companies having at least one employee named "Ayende"
IQueryable<Company> companies = from c in session.Query<Company>()
                                where c.Employees.Any(employee => employee.Name == "Ayende")
                                select c;
```

Comment: Downvote?  Really?  Any reason?

Comment: Seems to me the down vote was someone who did not understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is probably a type issue, this is ugly but have you tried this?

```
var project = _documentSession.Query<DeployProject>()
  .Where(i=>i.ComponentList.Any(j=>j.Id.ToString() == componentId.ToString()))
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

If this works then the original query is comparing two different types and not converting one of them correctly.

---

Try this, see if it gives you what you would expect...

```
var project = _documentSession.Query<DeployProject>()
      .Where(i=>i.ComponentList.Any(j=>j.Id == componentId))
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

I know it should be the same, but you can test it like this with the debugger to see what is returned:

```
var project = _documentSession.Query<DeployProject>()
      .Where(i=>i.ComponentList.Any(j=>j.Id == componentId))
      .ToList()
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Same result, I neglected to mention that in my original question (trying to be succinct), but yes I tried changing everything to .Where instead of .FirstOrDefault and it was still not finding any matching records (unless of course I move the .ToList() before the .Where or .FirstOrDefault, which case I'm searching memory instead of Raven)

Answer (score 0):

First, subselects aren't really straightforward at all -- that is a pretty hairly complex query from raven / LINQ's point of view. I would look at whatever ad-hoc index this is created and see if that actually does work.

A better approach here would be to build an index. Two approaches that strike me would be to build an index grouped by componentId with the deploy projects listed. Another would be to build a full-text style index with the componentId included and then you could ride lucene's rails very effectively.

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid of something like that.  Raven is awesome up until points like this, until the answer starts being "manually create an lucene index to map reduce the transformation of oh my god why is this so hard I just want to find the document that contains a certain record" :)

Comment: The other issue is that Raven's documentation says you should be able to do this: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/using-linq-to-query-ravendb.

Comment: @MikeMooney -- fair points though you have the same mental arithmetic with SQL we are just so used to it is internalized at this point :). Also, the docs don't imply first or default behavior there -- just that you can get the where clause. Check without first or default and see what comes out and see what the index is that ravendb creates. I'd also regression test back a version to see if that helps -- could be a new 2.5 bug you found.